# How does one get to this stage:

Tags: c#, php, javascript, asp.net, c++

Hey guys reading some of the posts I came to realise something:

[Reflecting parameter name: abuse of C# lambda expressions or Syntax brilliance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718037/abuse-of-c-lambda-expressions-or-syntax-brilliance)

Why is it that atm im learning how to implement operations but I have no bearing on the foundations its made of.

I can write a program to do a specific task but I dont know where its taking it from... kind of hard to explain what I mean but I dont understand what the system is doing for me. If that makes sense.

When will I get to the stage I truley understand C or any code? How can I get to that stage?

Comment: Are these questions not aloud?

Comment: From the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Comment: Ahhhh ok I understand my mistake, just hard to get a bearing on how to truely get to grips with programming

Comment: You should avoid making rant questions. You should consider learning some more about [Computer Science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science)

Comment: You may have more luck with this type of question on the [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: So.....what exactly are you asking? How does one become a zen master at programming? Practice grasshopper

Comment: 'Aloud' questions are permitted. However we'll never be able to answer unless you also type the text in. :)

Comment: True I would like others to explain but its been closed now, there must be a hitch hikers guide to the galaxy deep within SO. Im on a mission.

Comment: Charlie Sheen might hold the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question.

My answer is:

1. Learn hardware basics (e.g. I/O - memory .. etc)
2. Learn operating systems basics (e.g. threading - processes .. etc)
3. Learn networking basics (e.g. HTTP - TCP/IP - Data packets .. etc)

Comment: All of the above I have covered Nabeel, but im missing something. It might just be the sheer volume of information, is a good programmer one who has done it for years and knows and has attempted alot of operations or one who can understand the markup, I would like others to explain but I guess its been closed now.

Comment: Read lots of books. Reading the standard can be good fun too but it's definitely not an *easy* read because it's a formal document. You'll probably forget most of it (or get bored half way through) but you'll get a good idea of how C works and why some things are the way they are.

Comment: You forgot some points: -1. Learn physics (electricity, Maxwell's equations) 0. Learn electronics (integrated circuits etc)