# How to write join with composite key clause in FSharp query expressions?

Tags: join, f#, clause, c#-to-f#

How to write this C# join with composite key clause in F#? :

```
join k in DataContext.Catalogs on
   new { id = o.IDENT, v = o.VZ } equals
   new { id = k.IDENT, v = k.VZ }
```

This is similiar question to this:
[groupby multiple columns in a F# 3.0 query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650463/groupby-multiple-columns-in-a-f-3-0-query)
which is still not answered. But I can't believe it is not easy possible to write it in FSharp.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use tuples containing the key fields you want:

```
query {
  for o in DataContext.OTable do
  join k in DataContext.Catalogs on
   ((o.IDENT, o.VZ) = (k.IDENT, k.VZ))
  select (o.IDENT, k.VZ)
}
```

Note that you can't create an anonymous type with named fields in F#, like you can in C#.  Tuples are probably the closest and most idiomatic translation.  See Tomas's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8144299/1366219).