# Get name of function argument in higher-order function

Tags: java, android, reflection, kotlin, introspection

It seems that Kotlin does not support getting local functions etc. Please see the example below:

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.filterOnCondition(condition: (T) -> Boolean): MutableList<T>
{ 
    // For the printline, trying to get the function name, 
    // which in this case is passedAsCondition
    println(condition.reflect()!!.instanceParameter!!.name)
}

fun passedAsCondition (number: Int, multipleOf : Int): Boolean
{
    return number % multipleOf == 0
}

numbers.filterOnCondition { passedAsCondition(it, 5) }
```

Kotlin returns this error as it has not been mapped out yet:

> "kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KotlinReflectionInternalError:
>   Introspecting local functions, lambdas, anonymous functions and local
>   variables is not yet fully supported in Kotlin reflection"

(https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/reflection.jvm/src/kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/EmptyContainerForLocal.kt#L41)

BUT, surely this is possible to do via Java, is it not?

Comment: I can write `Arrays.asList(5, 6, 10, 13, 15, 24).stream().filter(x -> x % 5 == 0).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);` - not sure what you're asking... something about passing a function to filter?

Comment: I am trying to get the name of the function that is passed into filterOnCondition. For the println(), I would like to see passedAsCondition returned.

Comment: @Lander, You're reflecting on the lambda. `passedAsCondition` is in the lambda body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an anonymous function, thus it's name will be `<anonymous>`:

```
val x: (Int) -> Boolean = { passedAsCondition(it, 5) }
println(x.reflect()?.name) //prints <anonymous>
```

When you have a lambda `{ passedAsCondition(it, 5) }` how would you expect the reflection to work here? `passedAsCondition` is a simple call made inside the lambda, but you're invoking the `reflect` on an unnamed, anonymous, lambda, which does not have a name.

Ordinary functions can be used with method references which of course do have a name:

```
fun x(a: Int): Boolean {
    passedAsCondition(a, 5)
    return true
}
println(::x.name) //gives x
```

As a **result**, making use of proper reflection, the following works:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    mutableListOf(1).filterOnCondition(::passedAsCondition)
}


fun <T> MutableList<T>.filterOnCondition(
    condition: KFunction2<@ParameterName(name = "number") Int, @ParameterName(name = "multipleOf") Int, Boolean>
) {
    println(condition.name)
}

fun passedAsCondition(number: Int, multipleOf: Int): Boolean = number % multipleOf == 0
```

Comment: Thank you, s1m0nw1. I'm quite new to Kotlin here.

Is it possible to get the function name of passedAsCondition from within the lambda?

Comment: FWIW, if the question sounds unorthodox, you can actually do this in C#, where it used to be semi-common for passing a property name without using a hardcoded string.

Comment: An example of what @chris is referring to: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718037/reflecting-parameter-name-abuse-of-c-sharp-lambda-expressions-or-syntax-brillia)

Comment: @s1m0nw1: I see, but would you not lose the ability to pass params into passedAsCondition?

Comment: You can still invoke the function, but the arguments need to be passed as extra parameters but it quickly gets ugly tbh. What’s your use case anyways